# how to take only data key from NSManageobjectModel in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have an NSManageObjectModel instance

```
NSManagedObjectModel *selectedDevice = [self.devices objectAtIndex:tag];
```

its result is :

```
<NSManagedObject: 0x6000000b3800> (entity: History; id: 0xd000000000040002 <x-coredata://81B5B713-B1DB-4B22-AF6F-C41D4E093BEC/History/p1> ; data: {
    destinationLang = bn;
    group = arbn;
    sourceLang = ar;
    sourceText = Hhhhhhh;
    transilateText = "Hhhhhhh\n\n\nHhhhhhh";
})
```

but I want to only take "data" key portion. I tried in this way.

```
NSManagedObjectModel *selectedDevice = [self.devices objectAtIndex:tag]; 
NSMutableArray *store = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:selectedDevice, nil];
NSMutableArray *index0title = [[store objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"data"];
```

but I'm getting error.

Comment: What is your self.devices ?

Comment: self.devices is a NSMutableArray. where have the data of table view.

Comment: I give my code try it and make little changes as per your requirement .

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do. There is no "data" key on a managed object. That description shows all of the attribute values.